# Class loader not finding resources

Tags: java

I am creating a properties class that will ultimately be bundled into a jar for distribution. Because of this I'm trying to load the files that the properties are saved to via getResourceFromStream().

However, none of the various ways I've attempted to call it find the files.

The files I am trying to load are found in the Properties folder in the src folder. Their respective paths are "/System Properties/src/Properties/Default Properties" and "/System Properties/src/Properties/System Properties".

My build path contains the src folder and it's sub folders, so the files are on the build path.

Based on what I've read, I've tried the following ways of loading the files for testing:

```
getClass().getResource("/src/Resources/Default Properties"));
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/src/Resources/Default Properties");
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/src/Resources/Default Properties");
```

All of these methods return null.

using the following code generates Null Pointer Errors.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/src/Resources/Default Properties");
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/src/Resources/Default Properties");
```

Edit: My build path is System Properties/src.

The project has the following directory:
src
-Properties
--Default Properties
--System Properties

-systemproperties  //These three files contain the .java sources.

-systemproperties.activator

-systemproperties.internal

Comment: where is it relative to runtime classpath ?

Comment: Presumably the Resources folder is at the root of the class path so is should be `"/Resources/Default Properties"`

Comment: is your properties file within src?

Comment: @Guillaume The files are located in "System Properties/src/Properties/" and neither "/Properties/Default Properties" or "System Properties".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources loaded by the class loader obey the same rules as classes.

If a class is named `com.foo.bar.SomeClass`, it must be defined `com/foo/bar/SomeClass.java` in your src folder, and at runtime, the `com` directory must be in a directory or jar that is in the classpath. The corollary is that, if you find a file `zorg/bla/zim/Foo.java` in your src folder, the class name must be `zorg.bla.zim.Foo`.

For resources, it's the same. So if you find a resource named `Properties/Default Properties` in your src folder, its fully qualified resource name is `Properties/Default Properties`, and not `src/Resources/Default Properties`.

At runtime, the src folder is irrelevant. The src folder is where you store your source files. Only the classpath is used at runtime.

Comment: Turns out that I was using the incorrect path. Using Properties/Default Properties did end up working. It turned out that I was preceding it with an extra /, which caused it to fail.